# getting an Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'typeof Timestamp' error when converting firebase date

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a type error when trying Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'typeof Timestamp' to access toDate method on timestamp ? the firebase docs say time stamp should have this method available

[firebae 9 modular docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestamptodate)

```js
await getDoc(docData).then((docSnap) => {
      console.log(Timestamp.toDate(docSnap.data()?.createdAt.seconds));
          }
```